# java create time range attribute for data class

Tags: java, class, object, oop

I'm new to java and currently working on a small exercise. No external libraries. I have a [csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hc00mwse7hanomu/covid-data.csv?dl=0) consisting of data about covid cases. Now I need to create a class for this data. Each data object has two attributes: area and timerange. Area can be either continent or country. Time range is a pair of start date and end date. After entering the area and time range, it will display the rows fitting those entries. For example Vietnam and 6/1/2021 - 6/30/2021 will have the following results:
[image: 1]

This is the code to read csv lines:

```
File inputFile = new File("covid-data.csv");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputFile);
        String str;
        String[] tokens;
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            str = sc.nextLine();
            tokens = str.split(",");
            Data d = new Data(tokens[2], tokens[3]);
        }
```

And this is my data class:

```
public class Data {
    String area;
    String time_range;

    public Data(String a, String time) {
        area = a;
        time_range = time;
    }
```

I don't know how to deal with the time range so I can only assign it to 'time' column for now. External libraries can't be used here. Do I need to create a hashmap with separate start date and end date? Also do I need to convert to date format or keep it as string? Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

> No external libraries. I have a csv file consisting of data about covid cases.

Oof. Bad start. Reading CSVs is more complicated than you think and a very fine place for a dependency (for example, multi-line CSVs, which your code doesn't support. Your code will randomly start failing if any non-ASCII characters show up. Your code doesn't deal with quoted values. Your code doesn't let you easily marshall - all things CSV libraries do). Modern development is inherently bundled up with dependencies. Your aversion to them is something you need to fix.

Given a string containing a time range, you need to:

- Extract the start and end time, for example using `.split`.
- Convert the 'start' and 'end' string into a `java.time.LocalDate` instance, using `LocalDate.parse` and passing in the right format; it's probably just ISO format, there's a pre-fab DateTimeFormatter instance for it.
- Then a simple for loop does the job:

```
LocalDate start = ...., end = ....;
for (LocalDate current = start; !current.isAfter(end); current = current.plusDays(1)) {
    // this code is called once for each date, and `current` holds that date.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, both points in [Answer by rzwitserloot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68817340/642706) are correct and wise:

- Forbidding the use of external libraries means missing out on the best reason to use Java: its vast and rich ecosystem of supporting libraries.
- Use the *java.time* classes such as `LocalDate` for your work. Never use the legacy date-time class such as `Date` or `Calendar`.

Specifically, I suggest adding the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to make use of its [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class to contain a pair of `LocalDate` objects. That class offers handy methods such as `abuts`, `overlaps`, `contains`, and so on.

I suggest you do all your date-handling by defining a span-of-time using the Half-Open approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So the month begins on the first and runs up to, but does not include, the first of the following months. June would be June 1 to July 1. The `LocalDateRange` uses Half-Open by default, but can also accommodate Fully-Closed (beginning and ending both inclusive) if you insist.

In Java 16 and later, use the [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature to define a class to hold your data transparently and immutably. You merely declare the type and name of each member field. The compiler implicitly creates the default constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`. Bonus feature: a record can be defined locally in addition to nested or separately (ditto `enum` and `interface`).

So your entire class is one short line:

```
record CovidDaily ( String isoCode , String continent , String location, LocalDate date , … ) {}
```

To filter your rows, loop or use streams.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JUNE , 1 ) ;
LocalDate end = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JULY , 1 ) ;
List< CovidDaily > hits = new ArrayList<>() ;
List< CovidDaily > dailies = … ;
for( CovidDaily covidDaily: dailies ) 
{
    LocalDate ld = covidDaily.date() ;
    if( ( ! ld.isBefore( start ) ) && ( ld.isBefore( end ) ) 
    { hits.add( covidDaily) ; } // Else ignore this record and move on to next.
}
```

Generally best to return an unmodifiable result.

```
return List.copyOf( hits ) ;
```

Streaming approach is shorter.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JUNE , 1 ) ;
LocalDate end = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JULY , 1 ) ;
List< CovidDaily > dailies = … ;
return dailies.stream().filter( covidDaily -> ( ! covidDaily.date().isBefore( start ) ) && ( covidDaily.date().isBefore( end ) ) ).toList();
```

Using `LocalDateRange`.

```
LocalDateRange range = LocalDateRange.of( 
    LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JUNE , 1 ) ,
    LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JULY , 1 ) ) ;
List< CovidDaily > dailies = … ;
return dailies.stream().filter( covidDaily -> range.contains( covidDaily.date() ) ).toList();
```